# Norm of operator $\phi(f)=\int_{0}^{1}f(x^2)dx$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Does the map $\phi :L^3([0,1],\mathbb{C})\to \mathbb{C}$ such that $$\phi(f)=\int_{0}^{1}f(x^2)dx$$ define a bounded linear functional on the Banach space $L^3([0,1],\mathbb{C})?$ If yes, determine its norm.
Here linearity is obvious. i.e. $\phi(af+bg)=\int_{0}^{1}(af+bg)(x^2)dx=a\int_{0}^{1}f(x^2)dx+b\int_{0}^{1}g(x^2)dx=a\phi(f)+b\phi(g)$.

My confusion is on boundedness and its norm.

Comment: Can you write the map in the form $$\phi(f) = \int_0^1 f(x)\cdot g(x)\,dx\,?$$

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer.. How come? You mean as a composite?

Comment: Not really as a composite. Do you know a representation of the dual space of $L^3(I)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change variables, your integral will look like

$$\int_0^1 f(x) (d x/(2 \sqrt{x})).$$

This is an integral with respect to a finite measure, so is bounded. To find the norm, use Holder's inequality.

Comment: Thanks all! Now I understand it.

Comment: the operator is defined on $L^3([0,1])$ but not on $L^p([0,1])$ if $1\le p < 2$ as it contains $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, I don't see where you take that in account in your answer. and how do you find the minimum $p$ for which the operator is bounded ?

Comment: @user1952009 I did not realize that the OP asked for the minimum such $p$ ... :)

Comment: not saying he did, I do,

Comment: so Hölder inequality tells us $|\int_0^1 f(x) g(x) dx|  \le \|f\|_p \|g\|_q$ where $1/q + 1/p = 1$. with $g(x) = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}$ : $\|g\|_q^{\ q} = \frac1{2^q} \int_0^1 x^{-q/2} dx = \frac{1}{2^q (1-q/2)}$ iff $q < 2$. so the operator is bounded whenever $p = \frac{1}{1-1/q} > 2$, and the "finite measure" argument is that $\|g\|_{ \frac{1}{1-1/p}} < \infty$ ?